# Calculate a complex integral using residues

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Let $f(z)= \frac{2(e^\frac{1}{z}-1)(\sin^2z)}{z^3}$.
>
> Calculate $\int\limits_{\partial B_+(O,1)} f(z)\operatorname{d}z$

Could someone confirm my solution?

#### Solution?

I try to calculate the residue at $z=0$.

Since $e^\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2!z^2}+\frac{1}{3!z^3}+\ldots$
$$f(z)= \frac{1}{z^3}\left(-1+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2!z^2}+\frac{1}{3!z^3}+\ldots\right)\left(1-\cos 2z\right)$$
$$f(z)= \frac{1}{z^3}\left(-1+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2!z^2}+\frac{1}{3!z^3}+\ldots\right)\left(\frac{2^2z^2}{2!}-\frac{2^4z^4}{4!}+\frac{2^6z^6}{6!}-\ldots\right)$$

Since I would find the residue as the coefficient of $z^{-1}$, I'm looking for the terms containing $z^2$ originating from the last 2 factors.

This results in the following coefficients:
$$-2-\frac{2^4}{2!4!}+\frac{2^6}{4!6!}-\frac{2^8}{6!8!}+\ldots = -2+\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}2^{2n}}{(2n-2)!(2n)!}$$

As a conclusion using the residue theorem
$$\int\limits_{\partial B_+(O,1)} f(z)\operatorname{d}z = -4\pi i +2\pi i\left( \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}2^{2n}}{(2n-2)!(2n)!}\right)$$

I think it is correct, but the book where this problem originates from gives a solution without the term $-4\pi i$...

Comment: Bummer! After looking at the solution over and over I found a small error. The Taylor-expansion of $1-\cos 2z$ is wrong... However, the overall solution is still the same...

Comment: Check your Taylor expansion of $\exp$.

Comment: Oh boy, two silly errors in one exercise... Thanxs!